# Struggling to get working JavaScript working in WordPress

Tags: javascript, css, wordpress

I am trying to add advanced functionality to my client's WordPress website so I've turned to WPCode, but even after I have added it to the global header, activated it, updated it, cleared cache, added a cache plugin, etc, the script is nowhere to be found in the front end, basic console logs don't even fire.

I said screw it and turned to custom HTML code blocks with  tags, which does fire off the basic code-checking console logs, but the code never finds the blocks with custom classes that I am trying to target.

the code has devolved into checking for the desired blocks with classes, and waiting to see if it is taking the elements a while to become available --

```
<script>
   console.log('initial code running');
   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
       console.log('content loaded');

      // Function to check if the elements are ready
      const checkElements = () => {
         const titleText = document.querySelector('.title-text');
         const barberButton = document.querySelector('.barber-button');

         if (titleText && barberButton) {
            console.log('Elements are ready');
            console.log('titleText found');
            console.log('barber button found');
         } else {
            console.log('Elements are not yet ready');
            setTimeout(checkElements, 100); // Check again after 100 milliseconds
         }
      };

      // Start checking for elements
      checkElements();
   });
</script>
```

-- But no matter how long I wait they never show, and I have checked [x] number of times that the blocks have the right classes attached

[image: header with class of title-text]

Would appreciate any insights, suggestions, alternative approaches to adding advanced frontend functionality to wordpress.org websites, etc.

Answer (score 0):

The placement of JavaScript can often affect whether it works or not. In some cases, it will need to execute before the html/CSS definitions and some after. If you are using a snippet plugin in WP see if there is an option to place it in the footer/ body header and see if one of those works.